# How to create ISO from Application Bundle

Tags: macos, applications, iso

I have Mac OS X Mountain Lion as Application Bundle file. Burning the application to a disk is just like a data disk compilation on Nero.

How do I convert this application bundle into ISO image so that I can burn it on a disk and boot it from there?

Comment: What exactly are you after - booting of a CD requires the full OS, allowing to run the application of a CD is much simpler

Answer (score 5):

Right-click your "Install OS X Mountain Lion.app" file and select "Show Package Contents".
Open Contents/SharedSupport and then you will find InstallESD.dmg.

Copy this file to your Desktop. This is the file that you need to burn OS X to a DVD. **You need a Dual Layer DVD to burn OS X/or just use a USB flash drive**.

It isn't an ISO, but you can convert to a 'cdr' from Disk Utility. A 'cdr' file is the same as an 'iso' AFAIK, and you can rename the extension so that it is an ISO.

Answer (score -1):

```
sudo gem install iesd
iesd -i /Applications/Install\ OS\ X\ El\ Capitan.app  -o Desktop/Capitan.iso -t BaseSystem
```

Comment: Welcome to Ask Different and thank you for your answer. :) Unfortunately, short answers such as this don't really provide enough detail or context to help many users. If possible, it'd be good if you could add some more info, such as *how* a user would go about using your answer, etc. Also, you may want to read [How to Answer](http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/how-to-answer) for tips on providing answers here.